# Mount location by VidPid of a device

Tags: linux, mount, usb-storage

I am trying to figure out a way of getting to know where a mass storage device (pendrive, hdd) is mounted knowing only its Vendor and Product IDs. Is there a command (or a combination of many commands) that would allow me to get mounting location for given device?

I'm not too much Linux-savvy, having tried `dmesg`, `mount`, `lsusb (-t)` and `df` commands doesn't even give me a smallest clue on how to achieve this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is going to be part of a program used by general public, keep in mind that:

1. There can be multiple devices with the same VID:PID pair;
2. A single disk (even a USB stick) can have multiple partitions;
3. On Linux, the same partition (filesystem) can be mounted in several places at once.

That said:

First use udev to list all block devices whose parent has the needed VID:PID, either based on the ID_* properties or actual sysfs `idVendor, idModel` attributes:

```
$ udevadm trigger -v -n -s block -p ID_VENDOR_ID=3538 -p ID_MODEL_ID=0051
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3:1.0/host6/target6:0:0/6:0:0:0/block/sdb
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.3/2-1.3:1.0/host6/target6:0:0/6:0:0:0/block/sdb/sdb1
```

I *think* it's pretty safe to assume that the last part of the name will always match the `/dev` name...

Use `findmnt` to list the mountpoints:

```
$ findmnt -n -o TARGET /dev/sdb1
/run/media/grawity/A0D8-7268
```

In combination:

```
devs=$(udevadm trigger -v -n -s block -p ID_VENDOR_ID=… -p ID_MODEL_ID=…)

for dev in $devs; do
    findmnt -n -o TARGET /dev/${dev##*/}
done

# alternative, based on the device's major:minor
for dev in $devs; do
    findmnt -n -o TARGET $(<"$dev/dev")
done
```

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm. Also, thanks for the warnings, but it's for my usage only - and I will remember the caveats to this solution.

Comment: Just one question - should this also work with devices connected via Hub? `udevadm` doesn't seem to be able to find a device using it's vidpid when it's connected through a Hub, but maybe I lack a parameter or something.

Comment: Never mind, I had a typo in my command - it works with hubbed devices too.